# calling a function saved in a class attribute: different behavior with built-in function vs. normal function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

With the following script:

```
import time

class Foo(object):
    func = time.gmtime
    def go(self):
        return self.func(0.0)

print time.strftime('%Y', Foo().go())
```

I get the following output:

```
1970
```

However, if I make a slight modification and wrap `time.gmtime`:

```
import time

def tmp(stamp):
    return time.gmtime(stamp)

class Foo(object):
    func = tmp
    def go(self):
        return self.func(0.0)

print time.strftime('%Y', Foo().go())
```

then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print time.strftime('%Y', Foo().go())
  File "./test.py", line 11, in go
    return self.func(0.0)
TypeError: tmp() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Obviously it's trying to call `Foo.func` as if it was an instance method and passing `self` as the first argument.

Two questions:

- Both `time.gmtime` and `tmp` are functions that take a single argument, so why do the two scripts behave differently?
- How can I safely save an ordinary function in a class/instance attribute and call it later from an instance method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Both `time.gmtime` and `tmp` are functions that take a single argument, so why do the two scripts behave differently?

Let us understand what Python does when you do

```
self.func
```

from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects),

> When an instance attribute is referenced that isn’t a data attribute, its class is searched. If the name denotes a valid class attribute **that is a function object**, a method object is created by packing (pointers to) the instance object and the function object just found together in an abstract object: this is the method object. When the method object is called with an argument list, a new argument list is constructed from the instance object and the argument list, and the function object is called with this new argument list.

So, if `func` is a valid *function object* in `self`, then a bound method object will be created, which expects the first argument to be the object on which this function is invoked on.

Let us compare now,

```
print type(time.gmtime)

class Foo(object):
    func = time.gmtime
    def go(self):
        print type(self.func)
        return self.func(0.0)
```

When `go` is invoked with `Foo().go()`, it will print

```
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

That's right. Since `time.gmtime` is a built-in function (which is different from the function object), there is no bound method object created here. Lets try your second example now,

```
def tmp(stamp):
    return time.gmtime(stamp)

print type(tmp), tmp

class Foo(object):
    func = tmp
    def go(self):
        print type(self.func), self.func
        return self.func(0.0)
```

would print

```
<type 'function'> <function tmp at 0x7f34d9983578>
<type 'instancemethod'> <bound method Foo.tmp of <__main__.Foo object at ...>>
```

Since `tmp` is a function object, according to the documentation shown above, a bound method object is created and it expects an Object of `Foo` to be the first parameter. So, `tmp` is actually bound to `Foo` as an `instancemethod`. When you invoke `go` like `Foo().go()`, it internally calls `tmp` like this

```
Foo.func(self, 0.0)
```

which is effectively

```
tmp(self, 0.0)
```

That is why you are getting the following error

```
TypeError: tmp() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

> 2. How can I safely save an ordinary function in a class/instance attribute and call it later from an instance method?

**Solution 1:**

Quoting [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) again,

> It is also important to note that **user-defined functions which are attributes of a class instance are not converted to bound methods; this only happens when the function is an attribute of the class.**

It means that, when you assign a user defined function to a class variable, the bound method construction will happen. But, if you assign it to an instance then it will not happen.

So, you can use this to your advantage, like this

```
import time

def tmp(stamp):
    return time.gmtime(stamp)

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.func = tmp       # Instance variable, not a class variable

    def go(self):
        return self.func(0.0)

print time.strftime('%Y', Foo().go())
```

Here, `self.func` will translate to `tmp(0.0)`, as there is no bound method construction happening.

**Solution 2:**

Use [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) function like this

```
class Foo(object):
    func = staticmethod(tmp)

    def go(self):
        # `return Foo.func(0.0)` This will also work
        return self.func(0.0)
```

Now, `self.func` would still refer `tmp`. It is similar to defining your class like this

```
class Foo(object):

    @staticmethod
    def func(stamp):
        return time.gmtime(stamp)

    def go(self):
        # `return Foo.func(0.0)` This will also work
        return self.func(0.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the difference...:

```
>>> import time
>>> type(time.gmtime)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> def f(*a): return time.gmtime(*a)
... 
>>> type(f)
<type 'function'>
```

A `<type 'function'>` (which is a descriptor) is **not** the same thing as a `<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>` (which isn't)...

You ask "How can I safely save an ordinary function in a class/instance attribute and call it later from an instance method?".

If by "an ordinary function" you mean a `<type 'function'>`, then wrap it as a `staticmethod` to avoid `self` being inserted as the first argument when it's called.  And, it's OK to wrap a `staticmethod` around a built-in, too.  So I guess that's your best bet!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to to be stored as an instance attribute:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.func = tmp

    def go(self):
        return self.func(0.0)
```

You need to assign the function within the context of the instance, doing so in the initializer is a likely place.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I doubt it will help: you'll get a `NameError` on that `func(0.0)` call.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.  Removed the second snippet.  First one works though, if desired.