# Strange behavior assigning builtin methods as class attributes

Tags: python

I encountered a strange behavior that I cannot explain when assigning builtin methods as attributes to a class in Python.

If I run the following python file:

```
class A:
    a = bin
    b = lambda x: bin(x)
    
print(A().a(2))
print(A().b(2))
```

The call to `A().a(2)` returns a byte string, but the call to `A().b(2)` raises:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The signature of the builtin function `bin` is supposedly `bin(number, /)`, which seems identical to the signature provided by the lambda above. However, it appears as if `A().a` is treated as a static method, whereas `A().b` is treated like an "instance" method (with a `self` argument implicitly added to the provided lambda). There is an explanation of a similar issue here ([calling a function saved in a class attribute: different behavior with built-in function vs. normal function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007368/calling-a-function-saved-in-a-class-attribute-different-behavior-with-built-in)), which claims that the reason these two are treated differently is because one is a builtin_function_or_method and the other is a function type.

However, there is inconsistent behavior even within builtins.

```
class B(int):
    c = pow
    d = round

print(B(1).d(2))
print(B(1).c(2))
```

In the case of `pow` and `round`, `round` is treated like an instance method while `pow` is treated as a static method. Both of these builtins are callables capable of taking two unnamed arguments.

This behavior exists across all the versions of Python 2.* and 3.* I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007368/calling-a-function-saved-in-a-class-attribute-different-behavior-with-built-in) you've referenced is correct.
In the counter-example you gave the two built-in functions are indeed treated the same, that is no bound method object is created:

```
B(1).d(2) == round(2)  # not round(B(1), 2)
B(1).c(2) == pow(2)  # not pow(B(1), 2)
```

the issue arises from passing only one argument to `pow` which takes at least 2, as opposed to `round` which does only need one

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that round has a default value for the second argument.